# How to solve with steps (simple absolute value synthesis) |2x + 5| ≤ |x + 3|

Tags: absolute-value

|2x + 5| ≤ |x + 3|
I have the answer listed in front of me but it's not helping me figure out how to get there.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You could consider cases $x<-3$, $-3\le x\lt-2.5$, and $-2.5\le x$ separately, so you know the absolute values

Comment: I think I might have not asked for the right thing. The answer is $$[- \frac{8}{3},-2]$$

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to square both sides:

$$(2x+5)^2\le (x+3)^2$$

$$4x^2+20x+25\le x^2+6x+9$$

$$3x^2+14x+16\le 0$$

$$(3x+8)(x+2)\le0.$$

If a product of two terms is negative, one is negative and one is positive.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think I might have not asked for the right thing. The answer is $$[-\frac{8}{3},-2]$$

Comment: That looks right.  In that interval, $3x+8$ is non-negative and $x+2$ is non-positive